# What is the correct way to implement this do while?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, user-interface, while-loop

I start my GUI like this, which seems correct.

```
  javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            JFrame gui = new JFrame();
            gui.setExtendedState(JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);
            gui.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

At a certain point in the application, the playTurn() method gets fired. The for loops all turns in the list.

```
 for (String turn : controller.getTurns()) {
                playTurn(turn);
            }
```

I now load the correct panel with my CardLayout which worked fine. Then I had to write the playTurn() method. So playTurn() gets called. It should do certain things according to some variables. But it should not return until some buttons are disabled. This is what I can't achieve, the program just stops working. I can guess it's in the direction of threads etc.. but can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance.

```
public void playTurn(String turn) {
    if (controller.givePlayers().contains(turn)) {
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (!turnFinished) {
                    if (!button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled()) {
                        turnFinished = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    } else {
        deletePlayer(turn);
    }
}
```

Sorry for bad formatting. Couldn't find where.

EDIT:
The GUI stops being responsive. Can't close program either. 
I tried using a SwingWorker for the while which does not block the GUI but still playTurn() returns.

I have even tried creating a new thread where I call the method. The doesn't get blocked anymore but the method still returns.

```
Thread one = new Thread() {
                    public void run() {
                        playTurn(turn);
                    }
                };
```

FIXED: Placing the runnable up higher in the stack;

Comment: Active waiting is (very) rarely a good idea. You should be listening for an event instead. Apart from that, is turnFinished declared volatile ?

Comment: I can imagine it is not a good idea. I just don't see a direct other solution. No it is not volatile, didn't get to that part yet (learning  volatile).

Comment: "not return until some buttons are disabled. This is what I can't achieve, the program just stops working", need to be more specific with what you mean by stops working, the function crashes somewhere in there, doesn't return, or does return but before buttons are disabled?

Comment: The GUI stops being responsive. Can't close program either.

Comment: Not a swing programmer, so I don't know this for certain, but if playTurn() is called in response to an event, then I don't think swing is going to be able to handle any other events until playTurn() returns.

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too. I could rewrite a chunk of code. But we are talking about 4000-6000 lines of code.

Comment: Did you look at [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) about concurrency in Swing ?

Comment: I have :) How would I otherwise use workers and such?

Comment: StackOverflow is full of surprises... (e.g. people trying to work with copy-pasted code found who knows where).

Comment: Just to add @Zoyd : I tried using a SwingWorker for the while which does not block the GUI but still playTurn() returns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `playTurn` method runs the code on the [EDT](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/dispatch.html), cause of this line `javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {`, which makes your application GUI unresponsive as GUI-changing code must generally be run on the `EDT`. Since your buttons won't change from your GUI, once the loop starts, it might just loop forever.

By running the code in another `Thread`, you won't freeze your GUI. I'm guessing, since you don't provide much informations on the rest of your code, that you might have to change the way you handle things once your loop is done.

Edit from comments : Since you don't want `playTurn` to return, don't use a thread within it and make sure `playTurn` is not running on the `EDT`. Your `playTurn` method will return after creating and making a new `Thread` run the code.

You might want to try dong it like this :

```
Runnable code = new Runnable() {
  @Override
  public void run() {
    for (String turn : controller.getTurns()) {
      playTurn(turn);
    }
  }
};

if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {
  code.run();
} else {
  new Thread(code).start();
}
```

To make sure you don't run the code on the `EDT`. That way, `playTurn` doesn't return until the loop condition is met, the `GUI` stays responsive.

```
public void playTurn(String turn) {
  if (controller.givePlayers().contains(turn)) {
    while (!turnFinished) {
      if (!button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled() && !button1.isEnabled()) {
        turnFinished = true;
      }
    }
  } else {
    deletePlayer(turn);
  }
}
```

Doing this might have you change a few things more.

The idea is to make the call to a new `Thread` where you don't want it/need it to wait for the code being run in a new `Thread` to end to continue.

Comment: My buttons will change from the GUI already present. For example a button press will make all buttons setEnabled(false);

Comment: I might just have to take the hard way then and rewrite alot.

Comment: I must add that I want it to return but only if all buttons aren't enabled anymore.

Comment: Your possible solution is coming close. When removing the  isEventDispatchThread (with it doesn't work, also freezing) but using the runnable, and adding a JOptionPane in the while I clearly see it waiting because the JOptionPane keeps popping up (my gui also draws) BUT without the JOptionPane nothing draws and it stays unresponsive. Any explanation for this?

Comment: The condition `if (!SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread()) {` should return `true` when you're not on the `EDT`. This should make sure your `GUI` doesn't freeze. I find it strange to it does with it. Also, I just noted that you check `!button1.isEnabled()` four times in your loop, shouldn't it be `button1`, `button2` etc?

Comment: The buttons are correct here sorry for that. I just noticed something. The method calling playTurn() finishes before playTurn(); and it still does not wait. With the exact code you gave above

Comment: Then you need to move the `Runnable` part of the code to call that method instead or even before. The idea is to make the call to a new `Thread` where you don't want it/need it to wait for the code being run in a new `Thread` to end to continue.

Comment: I only have one last question I have a JTable that stopped responding after that (probably because it was made before and stuff runs on other threads now. All the other parts of GUI work, any tips on a workaround?

Comment: Without the code, hard to tell why it would stops and the rest doesn't. Make sure that it isn't waiting on the threads that are now being made.

Comment: I have solved it. Had to create the JPanel which holds the code for my problem above before the Thread we created. Like you said make sure it isn't waiting. My understanding about threads has increased. I must thank you sir. I would upvote you but I can't.